# Low CPU usage during extensive R calculations in Azure container instances

Tags: r, docker, debian, azure-container-instances

I'm calculating heavy R workloads on ACI in a Docker container (https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/r-ver Tag 3.5.3).
The calculations are working in ACI, but it's slower than expected. When observing the CPU metrics in Azure portal I see that the maximum CPU usage throughout the whole process is at ~1.5 vCPU although I reserved 4 vCPUs.

Is there a tweak to this? I found nothing in the Docker and Azure documentation.

Kind regards

Comment: What do you calculate/which functions do you use? Without any code it's difficult to help. And most importantly: is your code parallelised?

Comment: Well, I'm an idiot I forgot to activate the parallelisation. You made a perfect guess :)